# Performance and memory wise difference between chdir and cd

Tags: perl

I wanted to know whether using chdir, opendir,readdir commands of perl should be used or shell commands such as cd and ls. Same functionality can be achieved in both cases, but in terms of memory and performance efficiency, which one is better to use?

Answer (score 1):

Shell command `cd` would execute in a subshell and its effects would disappear when the subshell returned.

As to `ls`, running within the current process would be much more efficient than launching a new shell process just to execute `ls`.

Comment: ... especially if you need to parse the output of `ls`, which is not consistently structured.